# MongoDB query for count

Tags: mongodb, count

I want to count the number of fields with the name `appId` by `month`, `day` and `year`.

I know in SQL you could do something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(appID)
FROM stats
GROUP BY YEAR(record_date), MONTH(record_date), DAY(record_date)
```

How does that translate to mongodb? I tried this:

```
{
  $group : {
    _id: {      
      month : { $month : "$date" },        
      day : { $dayOfMonth : "$date" },
      year : { $year : "$date" },
    },
    count: { $sum: * } //*all the fields?
  }
}
```

Also how would I count the number of `appId` where `criticalThreshold` is greater than `critical`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there, just add up "1" for each record in the group and you've got it.

```
{
  $group : {
    _id: {      
      month : { $month : "$date" },        
      day : { $dayOfMonth : "$date" },
      year : { $year : "$date" },
    },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}
```

For the second question, you'll probably want to look at the aggregation framework:

```
db.stats.aggregate([ 
{ "$match": { "criticalThreshold": { $gt: "critical" } } },
{ "$group": 
   {
    _id: 
    {      
      month : { $month : "$date" },        
      day : { $dayOfMonth : "$date" },
      year : { $year : "$date" },
    },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
  }
}
])
```